# How to deal with the flask_jwt_extended import error?

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt-extended

I tried to use the flask_jwt_extended. However, I got an error when running the code `from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token, get_jwt_identity, jwt_required, current_user`.

It showed `ImportError: cannot import name 'DecodeError' from 'jwt' (unknown location)`.

I asked the GitHub Copilot and it told me to uninstall jwt and install PyJWT, I followed.

But the error still exist. How can I deal with the error?

Answer (score 1):

I resole this problem by uninstalling `jwt`, and reinstalling `pyjwt` and `flask-jwt-extended`.

Refre to this issue:
https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/issues/456